# Create a function to compare 2 numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a function to calculate the sum, product, and see which number is greater. I have the sum and product, but when I try to compare the 2 numbers, it won't work. I'm trying to get all 3 items (sum, product, and comparison) to show when the button is clicked. Here is the code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Please enter two numbers</h1>
    <p>First number: <input type="number" id="num1">&nbsp;&nbsp; Second number: <input type="number" id="num2"></p>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onclick="calculate()">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="result">
  </div>

  <!-- Function -->
  <script>
    function calculate() {
      var x = document.getElementById("num1").value;
      var y = document.getElementById("num2").value;
      var sum = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
      var product = parseInt(x) * parseInt(y);

      document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = ("The sum is " +
        sum + " and the product is " + product);
    }
  </script>

  <!-- This was the if statement that won't work. I was placing this in the same function right after the 1st querySelector.

    if (x > y) {
      document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = (x + " is greater than " + y);
    } else {
      document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = (y + " is greater than " + x);
    }  
    -->
```

Comment: Use `parseInt`. It's a string otherwise. Moreover move your javascript code into the `script` tag. Otherwise it's interpreted as html.

Comment: Is the `if` statement supposed to be outside of the `script` tags or is there another script block that isn't being shown?

Comment: Are you sure you're ok with only using integer numbers? `5.2` and `2` will equal `10`

Answer (score 0):

I moved the cast of `x` and `y` into integers to the assignment of that variables. Afterwards you can just use them as integers without worrying.

```js
function calculate() {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
  var sum = x + y;
  var product = x * y;

  document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = ("The sum is " +
    sum + " and the product is " + product + ". ");

  if (x > y) {
    document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML += (x + " is greater than " + y);
    // TODO: what about x == y ?
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML += (y + " is greater than " + x);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Please enter two numbers</h1>
    <p>First number: <input type="number" id="num1">&nbsp;&nbsp; Second number: <input type="number" id="num2"></p>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onclick="calculate()">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="result">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse the numbers several times. Parse them once and then use the parsed values.

Similarly, don't use `querySelector` to get the same element several times, use it once and save it into a variable that you can use later.

And since you're getting the element by ID, then it is better to use `getElelementByID()` instead of `querySelector()`.

```js
function calculate() {
  var x = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  x = parseInt(x);
  y = parseInt(y);

  var sum = x + y;
  var product = x * y;
  var result = document.querySelector("#result");

  result.innerHTML = "The sum is " + sum + " and the product is " + product + "<br/>";

  if (x > y) {
    result.innerHTML += x + " is greater than " + y;
  } else {
    result.innerHTML += y + " is greater than " + x;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Please enter two numbers</h1>
    <p>First number: <input type="number" id="num1">&nbsp;&nbsp; Second number: <input type="number" id="num2"></p>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onclick="calculate()">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="result">
  </div>
```

Comment: `parseFloat` would be a better option. There is no comment on the number type. Even then, this is under the assumption that the user inputs a valid number to begin with, unless he/she is cool with `parseFloat('24w.1212')` equalling `24`.

Comment: @Andrew The OP used `parseInt()` and seemed to be content with it. His question was only about adding the comparison. There is no point in speculating on the type and adding data validation, etc... We're not writing the entire script, we're only answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your Problem is that in your code you are overwriting your div element twice.for ex Your div element result for:

```

```
 if (x > y) {
      document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = (x + " is greater than " + y);
    } else {
      document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = (y + " is greater than " + x);
    }
```

```

is replaced by immediate following value:

```

```
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = ("The sum is " +sum + " and the product is " + product);
```

```
I suggest you to either concatenate both innerHTML values or make a seperate div element for either of them.

Hope this will help you.